# python scheduling - How can I avoid the infinite loop?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

First, my code is here:

```
import schedule # see https://github.com/dbader/schedule
import crawler

def job():
    print("Start my scheduled job...")
    cw.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cw = crawler.crawler()

    print("Initial crawling...")
    cw.run()

    schedule.every(10).seconds.do(job)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        for title, link in zip(cw.titles, cw.links):
            print("%s[%s]" % (title, link))
```

In the `while` loop, I want to execute the `for` loop only after the scheduled job finish.

But, that `for` loop is running infinitely.

I know why. But I don't know how to fix it.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: @nfnneil `run_pending()` returns only `None`, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this one?

```
def job():
    print("Start my scheduled job...")
    cw.run()
    for title, link in zip(cw.titles, cw.links):
        print("%s[%s]" % (title, link))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cw = crawler.crawler()

    print("Initial crawling...")
    cw.run()

    schedule.every(10).seconds.do(job)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
```

I just moved the `for` loop into `job()`.

Comment: This is a better implementation +1

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is a better way, but what about just putting the `for` loop in a function and then passing `schedule.run_pending()` into it as a dummy argument. Like this:

```
def foo(dummy):
    for title, link in zip(cw.titles, cw.links):
        print("%s[%s]" % (title, link))

while True:
    foo(schedule.run_pending())
```

I haven't tested this code, but I think it should work. Good luck.